# Eclipse PyDev AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python, eclipse, shopify, pydev

I am trying to connect to the shopify api but am having difficulty connecting when using Eclipse+PyDev. When connection via python in a bash shell the same commands work OK

to install:

```
pip3 install --upgrade ShopifyAPI
```

shopify.py (my code)

```
import shopify
shop_url = "https://APIKEY:PASSWORD@mystore.myshopify.com/admin/products.json
shopify.ShopifyResource.set_site(shop_url)
```

The reference to shopify.ShopifyResouce.. throws the following in PyDev:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ShopifyResource'
```

I think it may be due to relative imports in the shopify module (the same code works fine in a terminal).

In shopify.py: (shopify API)

```
from shopify.resources import *
```

in shopify.resources: (shopify API)

```
from ..base import ShopifyResource
```

When I run

```
from shopify.base import ShopifyResource
ShopifyResource.set_site(shop_url)
```

I get ImportError: No module named 'shopify.base'; 'shopify' is not a package

Any ides how I can fix this?

Comment: You named a module `shopify.py`. It is imported instead of the library. Just rename it.

Comment: @KlausD. Well spotted. Works now. If you can put this as an answer I will accept so that this question is not left hanging.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be you created a shopify.py file in your IDE rename that file and that error will be solved